# Selection row disable/reenable text selection

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code which selects multiple row when shift key is pressed. But whenever selection starts, the table text always gets selected, hence I tried to add disableSelection( ); to the table and re-enable it once mouseup. However, it is not working, the text still get selected. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
$(".tableGrid tr").live("click", function(event) {
    if( event.shiftKey ) {
        $(".tableGrid").disableSelection( );
    }
    var tableRow = $(this).closest("tr").prevAll("tr").length + 1;
    if ($(this).hasClass("rowSelected")) {
        event.shiftKey ? $(this).removeClass("rowSelected") : $(".tableGrid tr").removeClass("rowSelected");
    }
    else {
        if( !event.shiftKey ) {
            $(".tableGrid tr").removeClass("rowSelected");
        }
        $(this).addClass("rowSelected");
    }

    if( event.shiftKey ) {
        var start = Math.min(tableRow, lastSelected);
        var end = Math.max(tableRow, lastSelected);
        for( var i=start; i<end; i++ ) { $(".tableGrid").find("tr").eq(i).addClass("rowSelected"); }
    }
    else {
        lastSelected = $(this).closest("tr").prevAll("tr").length + 1;
    }
}).mouseup(function( ) {
    $(".tableGrid").enableSelection( );
});
```

Comment: I have removed the mouseup event as I realized it should not be in conjunction with click event.

Answer (score 0):

To disable text selection of a specific DOM element, you could try this:

```
var element = document.getElementById('content');
element.onselectstart = function () { return false; } // ie
element.onmousedown = function () { return false; } // mozilla
```

Comment: Thanks Kyle, i tried adding your code but now even my table row is not being selected.